# Разбить строку на блоки и занести в массив

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Вводится строка, программа разбивает её на блоки по 8 символов, и заносит каждый блок в следующую ячейку массива.

Пример. Ввод:

```
string s="abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcd";
```

Программа должна разбить его по блокам и занести в массив так, что значения в ячейках массива будут следующие:

```
m[0] = "abcdefab"
m[1] = "cdefabcd"
...
```

Как, собственно, реализовать такой алгоритм на языке C++?

Comment: В чем заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: как это сделать на с++

Comment: string a = "160 symbols"; m[0] = a / 20; только по порядку следования как-то

Comment: @Эникейщик обновил вопрос

Comment: @vbujym, будьте добры соблюдать сложившуюся у нас дружелюбную атмосферу

Comment: @ЮрийСПб извиняюсь, но дружелюбия не заметил, по вопросу есть что посоветовать, я здесь не в поиске нравоучений

Comment: @vbujym, ну... Мы ж вас не забанили сразу за мат) А вообще, у нас даже в [справке написано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), что мы за дружелюбие. Если вы где-то заметили не соответствующее нашим высоким стандартам сообщение - смело жмите на "тревогу" и мы, модераторы, придём и уладим конфликт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char* s = "abcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcdefabcd";
    // Убедитесь, что для подстрок хватит места!
    // Длина каждой строки = 8 + 1 (для '\0').
    char m[64][9];

    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < strlen(s); i += 8, k++) {
        strncpy(m[k], s+i, 8);
        m[k][8] = '\0';

        printf("%s\n", m[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо! все оказалось очень просто, буду разбираться как раскидать это на 2 массива

Comment: а перевод char в uint32_t возможен после этого преобразования в массив?

Comment: Конечно, ведь `char` - просто число!

Comment: выдает ошибку, я просто добавляю for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {m[i] = w[i];}

Comment: Если `m[i]` и `w[i]` - строки, то это естественно. Строки в С нельзя складывать как числа. Попробуйте `strcpy(m[i], w[i])`, т.е. копируем строку `w[i]` в строку `m[i]`.

Comment: в итоге мне нужен формат uint32_t, нужно какое-то преобразование типа, исходная строка в hex формате и мне нужно разбить её на 32 битные числа

Comment: Т.е. у вас строка вида `0x0000000x0000010x000002`? Тогда нужно делать как-то так: `m[i] = atoi(w[i])`. Функция `atoi` преобразует строку в число.

Comment: у меня формат без 0х, 16 знаков hex формата 0-9&a-f слитно без пробелов, хэш сообщений, вот например fe7a350206a156a39e3c18a30b363eb3846d1353af8d1157d39107134879fd4356acdecba41d4be32227fcf9be1af3c3e6aa8e1176730116917daf4ad3a738091ca5770f2A1961D5AF6D00018EA12E722

Comment: Понял. Я не прав, `atoi` не подойдет, у Вас же строки в `hex`. Смотрите http://www.cyberforum.ru/c-beginners/thread1501459.html.

Comment: спасибо, учу матчасть